# can't access values in useState using include ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Using the function includes i want to use conditional rendering to check if different id's exist in the arrray. no matter what value i put in the includes function it always returns false even if i put Null. When i tried to test the length function i get the correct length.

When i console log it i get all the values.

Decleration of useState:

```
     const [freeSlotsList, setFreeSlotsList] = useState([]);
  console.log(freeSlotsList)
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/get/week1/ex").then((response) => {
      setFreeSlotsList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
```

It's always false:

```
const renderTableData = () => {
let id = 1;
const activeButton = () => {};

return (
  <tr>
    {days.map((val) => (
      <td>
        {timeSlot.map((n, i) => {
          if (freeSlotsList.includes(id) == false) {
            return <h1>Testing</h1>;
          }

          return (
            <button id={id++} className={activeButton}>
              {n} {id}
            </button>
          );
        })}
      </td>
    ))}
  </tr>
);
```

};

Comment: Hey!  but `freeSlotsList` is an array of objects which contains a property `id`?

Comment: How about if you put `setFreeSlotsList([1]);` inside the .then callback?

Comment: I can't seem to put `setFreeSlotsList([1]); ` the page wont render at all then